# Java Dice Roll Program(Craps Game) Not Getting Output

Tags: java

I'm new to stackoverflow and java in general. I am currently working on a dice roll program game called Craps and I am having a difficult time finding the errors.

```
public class Craps {
   public static Random rand; //INITIALIZE RANDOM
   public static Scanner in; //INITIALIZE USER INPUT
   public static int numOfDice = 2; //INITIALIZE NUMBER OF DICES INVOLVED
   public static int numOfSides = 6; //INITIALIZE NUMBER OF SIDES INVOLVED

   static {
       rand = new Random();
       in = new Scanner(System.in);
   }
   public static int roll() { //ROLL DICE
       int dice1 = rand.nextInt(numOfDice + (numOfSides+1));//ROLL DICE 1 
       int dice2 = rand.nextInt(numOfDice+(numOfSides+1)); //ROLL DICE 2
       int roll = dice1 + dice2; //STORE THE VALUE OF THE TWO DICES
       return roll;
    }

   public static boolean round() {
       int firstPoint = roll(); //CHECK THE VALUE OF THE FIRST ROLL
       if (firstPoint == 7 || firstPoint == 11) { //IF THE VALUE IS EITHER 7 OR 11 IN THE FIRST ROLL YOU WIN
        System.out.println("You win!");
        } else if (firstPoint == 2 || firstPoint == 3 || firstPoint == 12) { //IF THE VALUE IS EITHER 2 3 OR 12 IN THE FIRST ROLL YOU LOSE
            System.out.println("You lose!");

        } else { //IF THE VALUE IS NEITHER OF THOSE ROLL AGAIN
            int secPhase = firstPoint;
            secPhase = 0;
            while (firstPoint != secPhase && firstPoint !=7) { //LOOP THIS UNTIL YOU GET AN OUTCOME
                if (secPhase == 7) {
                    System.out.println("You lose!"); //IF THE VALUE IS 7 YOU LOSE
                } else if (secPhase == firstPoint) {
                    System.out.println("You win!"); //IF THE VALUE IS THE SAME AS YOUR FIRST VALUE YOU WIN
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");
                }
                //KEEP ROLLING UNTIL YOU HAVE A WIN/LOSE    
            }
        }           
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
        int amtRound = in.nextInt();
        for (int i=1; i<=amtRound; i++) {
            boolean result = round();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it does ask me how many rounds I would like to play although it skips the entire process and just jumps to the `while` loop and prints the `System.out.print("Error. Please try again.");`

Comment: (Caveat: I'm not a Java developer) but it looks like you define `secPhase` and then immediately overwrite it, which I don't think is what you wanted. Also, you check to see if `secPhase` is 7 or the same as `firstPoint`, and since `firstPoint` is never 0 and you set `secPhase` to `0` neither of those conditions will ever be true, and you get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're calling it in a loop from main - your `else` case in round should be much simpler:

```
public static Random rand = new Random(); //INITIALIZE RANDOM
public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); //INITIALIZE USER INPUT
public static int numOfDice = 2; //INITIALIZE NUMBER OF DICES INVOLVED
public static int numOfSides = 6; //INITIALIZE NUMBER OF SIDES INVOLVED

public static int roll() { //ROLL DICE
    int dice1 = rand.nextInt(numOfDice + (numOfSides+1));//ROLL DICE 1
    int dice2 = rand.nextInt(numOfDice+(numOfSides+1)); //ROLL DICE 2
    int roll = dice1 + dice2; //STORE THE VALUE OF THE TWO DICES
    return roll;
}

public static void round() {
    int firstPoint = roll(); //CHECK THE VALUE OF THE FIRST ROLL
    if (firstPoint == 7 || firstPoint == 11) { //IF THE VALUE IS EITHER 7 OR 11 IN THE FIRST ROLL YOU WIN
        System.out.println("You win!");
    } else if (firstPoint == 2 || firstPoint == 3 || firstPoint == 12) { //IF THE VALUE IS EITHER 2 3 OR 12 IN THE FIRST ROLL YOU LOSE
        System.out.println("You lose!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("you tied!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
    int amtRound = in.nextInt();
    for (int i=1; i<=amtRound; i++) {
        round();
    }
}
```

Further, you can initialize variables upon declaration and you don't need `round()` to return any value since you're not doing anything with it anyways.

Example output:

```
How many rounds would you like to play?
7
you tied!
you tied!
you tied!
you tied!
you tied!
You win!
You lose!
```

Another way to implement it would be to pass `amtRound` to `round` and let it figure out how many times it should run in a loop (iteratively):

```
public static void round(int times) {
    while (times > 0) {
        int firstPoint = roll(); //CHECK THE VALUE OF THE FIRST ROLL
        if (firstPoint == 7 || firstPoint == 11) { //IF THE VALUE IS EITHER 7 OR 11 IN THE FIRST ROLL YOU WIN
            System.out.println("You win!");
        } else if (firstPoint == 2 || firstPoint == 3 || firstPoint == 12) { //IF THE VALUE IS EITHER 2 3 OR 12 IN THE FIRST ROLL YOU LOSE
            System.out.println("You lose!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("you tied!");
        }
        times--;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("How many rounds would you like to play?");
    int amtRound = in.nextInt();
    round(amtRound);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the help. I'm understanding the condensing of the round() method. Although, in the program exercise, my professor wanted us to have a "point phase," in which, if the first point is neither 7, 11, 2, 3, and 12, we roll again then check if it's the same as the first point or if it is a 7. He had also wanted us to display the values each roll then print if we win or lose. Does this mean I need to create an array to store the values? Or do they automatically stay in the output console and just keep rolling?

Comment: You don't need to store them in an array unless you want to do something with it later on. You can simply display the numbers that were rolled as them come.

Answer (score 1):

## `while` loop is locked

Since you never change `secPhase`, it will never stop. You probably want to do something like `secPhase = roll();` somewhere in the loop.

Also, you shouldn't do `int secPhase = firstPoint; secPhase = 0;`. Just do `int secPhase = 0;`.

Also, I don't think you even need the `while` loop to begin with.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for responding. My professor wanted us to have a "point phase," in which, if the first point is neither 7, 11, 2, 3, and 12, we roll again then check if it's the same as the first point or if it is a 7. If it equals to the first point, you win. if it's 7 in any other roll, you lose. Am I still able to eliminate the while loop?

Comment: @kbg2o You probably need the while loop in some form.  But you need to rethink how you're doing it.  `secPhase` should probably be set equal to a new roll of the dice, right?  And then you compare that roll to the first point, and to 7.